# How to delete selected row from a datagridwith context menu in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I need to be able to delete a selected row from a datagrid with "Delete” context menu item. I have hard time finding the path to the selected row. I am wondering if someone can look at the code below and let me know what will be the appropriate to do within my code. Thank you in advance.

XAML:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>     
    <local:MainPage_ViewModel/> 
</UserControl.DataContext>  
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">  

    <data:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Coordinates}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10">
        <!-- ContextMenu -->
          <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
             <toolkit:ContextMenu x:Name="Menu" >
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Edit" />
                <toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="Delete" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click" />
            </toolkit:ContextMenu>
        </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>      
        <data:DataGrid.Columns>             
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="X Position" Width="100" Binding="{Binding X}"/>             
            <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="Y Position" Width="100" Binding="{Binding Y}"/>             
            <data:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Delete Item" Width="100">                 
                <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                     
                    <DataTemplate>                         
                        <Button Content="Delete" Tag="{Binding}" Click="Button_Click"/>                     
                    </DataTemplate>                 
                </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>             
            </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>         
        </data:DataGrid.Columns>     
    </data:DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
        this.viewModel = this.DataContext as MainPage_ViewModel; 
    }

    private MainPage_ViewModel viewModel;      
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)     
    {         
        viewModel.DeleteCoordinate((sender as Button).Tag as Coordinate_DataViewModel);     
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainPage_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public MainPage_ViewModel()
    {
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate_DataViewModel(new Coordinate_Model() { X = 1, Y = 2 }));         
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate_DataViewModel(new Coordinate_Model() { X = 2, Y = 4 }));         
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate_DataViewModel(new Coordinate_Model() { X = 3, Y = 6 }));         
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate_DataViewModel(new Coordinate_Model() { X = 4, Y = 8 }));         
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate_DataViewModel(new Coordinate_Model() { X = 5, Y = 10 }));         
        coordinates.Add(new Coordinate_DataViewModel(new Coordinate_Model() { X = 6, Y = 12 }));
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Coordinate_DataViewModel> Coordinates     
    {         
        get { return coordinates; }         
        set          
        {             
            if (coordinates != value)             
            {                 
                coordinates = value;                 
                OnPropertyChanged("Coordinates");             
            }         
        }     
    }     
    private ObservableCollection<Coordinate_DataViewModel> coordinates = new ObservableCollection<Coordinate_DataViewModel>();      
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;      

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)     
    {         
        if (PropertyChanged != null)         
        {             
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));         
        }     
    }      

    public void DeleteCoordinate(Coordinate_DataViewModel dvmToDelete)     
    {         
        coordinates.Remove(dvmToDelete);     
    }

    public void UpdateCoordinate(Coordinate_DataViewModel dvmToDelete)
    {

    }
}

//Model
public class Coordinate_Model 
{     
    public double X;     
    public double Y; 
} 

//DataViewModel
public class Coordinate_DataViewModel 
{     
    public Coordinate_DataViewModel(Coordinate_Model model)     
    {         
        this.underlyingModel = model;     
    }     

    private Coordinate_Model underlyingModel;      
    public double X     
    {         
        get { return underlyingModel.X; }         
        set { underlyingModel.X = value; }     
    }      

    public double Y     
    {         
        get { return underlyingModel.Y; }         
        set { underlyingModel.Y = value; }     
    }      public string XYCoordinate     

    {         
        get { return "(" + X + "," + Y + ")"; }     
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your datagrid to bind to a selected item on your viewModel.  Update your datagrid as follows:

```
<data:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Coordinates}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="10" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

On your view model, add the following property:

```
public Coordinate_DataViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set { selectedItem = value; }
    }
    private Coordinate_DataViewModel selectedItem;
```

Then, you could add the following method to your view model:

```
public void DeleteSelectedItem()
    {
        DeleteCoordinate(this.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Now, hook up your 'Delete' button on the context menu to the DeleteSelectedItem() and you should be good to go.

Hope this helps!

**Edit for comment response:**
Here's an example of what you could add to implement the issue you mentioned in the comments where you don't always want to be able to delete the item.  Notice i added the INotifyPropertyChanged to the setter of the SelectedItem so that the bindings of IsDeletable will be updated.

```
public Coordinate_DataViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set 
        { 
            selectedItem = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsDeletable");
        }
    }
    private Coordinate_DataViewModel selectedItem;

    public Visibility IsDeletable
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedItem.Y == 2)
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I tried it. It looks like it is pretty much what I need. However, I am getting error that 'Event handler 'DeleteSelectedItem' not found on class 'ViewModelDeleteObject.MainPage'. Any ideas what can cause it. I also was wondering is it possible to get cell value of cetain column to make delete row conditional, based if the value of cell is not 2. I can get value only on selection changed but cannot connect it with the behavior to delete the row. Thank you a lot.

Comment: That's because it's not an event handler, it's a method on the viewModel.  You'll probably need to create an event on the codeBehind of MainPage, and from that call viewModel.DeleteSelectedItem().  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you again for your help! I am only woindering if it is easy to make the deleting row to be conditional. To be able to delete the row only if the value of cell of "Y coordinates" will not be 2. Please let me know.

Comment: Yeah, you could just put that logic in the "DeleteSelectedItem()" method.

Comment: Oh, I think I mis-read your statement. What I would do is create a new Visibility properyt called "IsDeletable" and you could bind to that in your contect menu. In the 'get' of the IsDeletable, you could do your logic. If it equals 2, return Visibility.Collapsed, else Visibility.Visible. Does that make sense?  I edited my answer to show some code for this.

Comment: Yes, you got it correctly now. I tried your code. Everything runs great, no errors. However, It still deletes any row. It does not see that value is 2 of row cell. Solution does not give any clue where to look. Sorry for bothering. I was wondering if it is simple thing to fix.

Comment: What Visibility is set to? Is that possible do not delete the row and make visible any button in UI?

Comment: The row cell that you are looking at is the Y coordinate, correct?  If so, I added logic for that in the 'get' of the IsDeletable property.  If you don't want it there, you could move that logic inside the DeleteSelectedItem().  My intention was for you to bind the 'Delete' button in the context menu to the visibility (IsDeletable) property.  This way, the 'Delete' would only show up if the Y does not eqaul 2.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunatelly, the visibility of 'Delete' button is always visible even when value of Y cell is 2.

Comment: Did you bind the 'Visibility' property of your 'Delete' to the 'IsDeletable' property?

Comment: Yes, I did it like this "<toolkit:MenuItem x:Name="m2" Header="Delete" Click="m2_Click" Visibility="{Binding IsDeletable}"/>". DataContext like this: this.viewModel = this.DataContext as MainPage_ViewModel;. it does not work yet.

Comment: Did you add OnPropertyChanged("IsDeletable") to the setter of the SelectedItem?

Comment: I have it like this: public Coordinate_DataViewModel SelectedItem { get { return selectedItem; } set { selectedItem = value; OnPropertyChanged("IsDeletable"); } }. I followed the code you provided. Perphaps, I missed something else, but I have every single line that you provided. I added it in viewmodel and call it on button click: private void m2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            viewModel.DeleteSelectedItem();
        }

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in the setter of the selectedItem, is it getting hit when you select a row?  If so, place a breakpoint on the getter of the IsDeletable property because it should also get called if your binding is set up correctly.

Comment: JSprang, it looks like it works. It is just looking weird with empty context menu. When, I added additional menuitem, it looked fine. Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah, works for me too.  Maybe it would be better to to change the IsDeletable to a boolean property and bind the IsEnabled property to it, then it would show, they just wouldn't be able to click it.

Comment: I will try that. Thank you again. I highly appreaciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the data grids SelectedItem to a property in your ViewModel.  Use commanding to fire a method in your ViewModel when the delete button is clicked.  Then remove the item from the ObservableCollection.

If you want to delete multiple items:
[Handling DataGrid.SelectedItems in an MVVM-friendly manner](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/05/19/handling-datagrid.selecteditems-in-an-mvvm-friendly-manner.aspx)